# Insufficient Permissions to access a report?

Tags: reporting

Currently I am trying to access a report on salesforce that all users should have access to but for some reason I am not able to. The error that occurs when opening the particular report is:
**Insufficient Privileges**
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

Some things to note:
 - The folder the report is located in is public read
   only
 - The user has the permissions needed to access every field within the report itself and can access the objects as well
 - The report is one of many managed reports (from one package) in the folder (the only of which is inaccessible)
 - The other reports within the folder use similar if not the same fields yet are accessible. 
 - Standard report visibility is on

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possible causes here. Best way to find what is causing the access restriction is to follow [this checklist](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005189&type=1&language=en_US) in Salesforce help.